# How to rename a file using Python

Tags: python, file-rename

I want to change `a.txt` to `b.kml`.

Answer (score 1113, accepted):

Use [`os.rename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename):

```
import os

os.rename('a.txt', 'b.kml')
```

Usage:

```
os.rename('from.extension.whatever','to.another.extension')
```

Comment: Should be noted that if the files are not in the working directory you will need the full path.

Comment: not really, on 3.7 ubuntu, works for me using relative paths

Comment: @toing_toing of course it works, he probably just means that you should be aware of the current directory, and either specify the path relative to it, or just use the absolute path (like `C:/folder/file.txt` on Windows or `/home/file.txt` on Linux/MacOS).

Comment: It's worth noting that this will silently overwrite files on Unix-like systems but fail with `OSError` on Windows systems. `os.path.exists` should be used to check if the target exists before renaming. This does create a "Time Of Check to Time Of Use" bug, but it's unlikely to cause issues. (I know of no easy way around this - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222341/how-to-rename-without-race-conditions).

Comment: If the user actually wants the file to be replaced on any operating system, one should use `os.replace`

Comment: `os.rename` only works if source and destination are on the same file system. If you are on the differrent file system you should use `shutil.move` instead.

Comment: @AnnanFay `FileExistsError` is raised now instead of `OSError` when trying to overwrite the destination. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68733161/10792235) for using `os.replace` instead as suggested by @LucG

Comment: for file I guess `rename` is the bad idea to change the extension of a file I have rename pdf file to docx file by this method but it cause problem while opening renamed file

Answer (score 155):

File may be inside a directory, in that case specify the path:

```
import os
old_file = os.path.join("directory", "a.txt")
new_file = os.path.join("directory", "b.kml")
os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Answer (score 107):

As of Python 3.4 one can use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module to solve this.

If you happen to be on an older version, you can use the backported version found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)

Let's assume you are not in the root path (just to add a bit of difficulty to it) you want to rename, and have to provide a full path, we can look at this:

```
some_path = 'a/b/c/the_file.extension'
```

So, you can take your path and create a `Path` object out of it:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(some_path)
```

Just to provide some information around this object we have now, we can extract things out of it. For example, if for whatever reason we want to rename the file by modifying the filename from `the_file` to `the_file_1`, then we can get the filename part:

```
name_without_extension = p.stem
```

And still hold the extension in hand as well:

```
ext = p.suffix
```

We can perform our modification with a simple string manipulation:

Python 3.6 and greater make use of f-strings!

```
new_file_name = f"{name_without_extension}_1"
```

Otherwise:

```
new_file_name = "{}_{}".format(name_without_extension, 1)
```

And now we can perform our rename by calling the `rename` method on the path object we created and appending the `ext` to complete the proper rename structure we want:

```
p.rename(Path(p.parent, new_file_name + ext))
```

More shortly to showcase its simplicity:

Python 3.6+:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(some_path)
p.rename(Path(p.parent, f"{p.stem}_1_{p.suffix}"))
```

Versions less than Python 3.6 use the string format method instead:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(some_path)
p.rename(Path(p.parent, "{}_{}_{}".format(p.stem, 1, p.suffix))
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of the accepted answer? Seems far more complicated

Comment: Well @rbennell, most of this answer is an explanation. The answer is really just the three lines at the end. Furthermore, the accepted answer is made explicitly for that very name change. This answer provides a way to show how you can manipulate the filename to preserve parts that you want in the path or name of the file. Furthermore, the `pathlib` library is introduced in python 3.4 so sharing the answer here also provides exposure for a solid module to showcase its versatility and usage for more complicated requirements.

Comment: Thank you @idjaw, your comment is a good answer to a basic question of us beginners, a simple _Why did you did that?_. Also, it is refreshing to see non-hostile approach on internet to what is often considered as ignorant.

Comment: can you explain line : `new_file_name = "{}_{}".format(name_without_extension, 1)` ? What is `{}_{}` ? where can I read more about it?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha - The `{}` are for string formatting, which you can read about [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-examples). Ultimately, what is happening is that the `{}` get replaced with the variables that are passed in to the `format` method. So the first `{}` will hold what is in `name_without_extension`, and the second will hold the second argument which is simply `1`.

Comment: In addition to the python docs. http://pyformat.info has lots of easy to read explanations and examples of all kinds of python string formatting

Comment: Using f-strings simplifies it even more.  
from pathlib import Path  
p = Path(some_path)  
version = 1  
p.rename(Path(p.parent, f"{p.stem}_{version}" + p.suffix))

Comment: +1 for f-strings @idjaw can you add them in so that others can benefit ? :) thanks for the awesome post.

Comment: @Datanovice Thanks for the edit and ping. I was meaning to update this and forgot. Cheers.

Comment: Just best to put both, however, because it is still quite likely people might not be necessarily on Python 3.6.

Comment: That's fine, your post helped me solve some complex I/O operations at work. My thanks to you for helping the community!

Comment: It seems like ugly code to me because you need to create two `Path` objects:`# first_one p = Path(some_path)
p.rename(# second_one Path(p.parent, f"{p.stem}_1_{p.suffix}"))`

Comment: Great answer :). A minor simplification: `p.rename(p.parent / f"{p.stem}_1_{p.suffix}")` works too since `p.parent` is already a Path instance.

Comment: Thing to keep in mind about complexity of `path` to `os.rename` is that, in the os rename case you already have to know the new name.  If that requires substantial calculation (which is not the case in this Q) then you will have to do it yourself, which is not always  easy when paths are concerned.  On the other hand pathlib provides many name manipulation facilities.  Note that `Path("a.txt").rename("b.kml")` is **all you really need to do what OP was asking for**.

Comment: +1 I love `pathlib` but had no idea I could call `rename` directly on the Path object and it would change the file!

Answer (score 74):

```
import shutil

shutil.move('a.txt', 'b.kml')
```

This will work to rename or move a file.

Comment: `shutil.move` is not a good option due to not being an atomic operation. If the file is open, for instance, `shutil.move` will create a file with `new_name`, but will not delete the file with `old_name` hence leaving you with two files.
`os.rename` on the other hand will do nothing, which is a *better option*.
With `shutil.move`, even if you caught the error, you would still have to worry about checking and deleting the rogue file. Just not worth it when **a better tool exists: `os.rename`**.

Comment: @mvbentes it would be interesting to know the behaviour of `pathlib` respectively `Path` with renaming open - windows - files.

Answer (score 22):

`os.rename(old, new)`

This is found in the Python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

Answer (score 15):

As of Python version 3.3 and later, it is generally preferred to use `os.replace` instead of `os.rename` so `FileExistsError` is not raised if the destination file already exists.

```
assert os.path.isfile('old.txt')
assert os.path.isfile('new.txt')

os.rename('old.txt', 'new.txt')
# Raises FileExistsError
os.replace('old.txt', 'new.txt')
# Does not raise exception

assert not os.path.isfile('old.txt')
assert os.path.isfile('new.txt')
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace).

Answer (score 14):

Use `os.rename`. But you have to pass full path of both files to the function. If I have a file `a.txt` on my desktop so I will do and also I have to give full of renamed file too.

```
os.rename('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\a.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\b.kml')
```

Comment: "Have to" isn't true. You can always substitute a relative file name for an absolute file name, and vice versa. What usually bites beginners is they don't understand how relative file names relate to the current working directory.

Answer (score 4):

One important point to note here, we should check if any files exists with the new filename.

suppose if b.kml file exists then renaming other file with the same filename leads to deletion of existing b.kml.

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('b.kml'):
    os.rename('a.txt','b.kml')
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to race conditions. Prefer using either `os.rename` in a `try`/`except` or `os.replace`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

# Set the path
path = 'a\\b\\c'  
# save current working directory
saved_cwd = os.getcwd()
# change your cwd to the directory which contains files
os.chdir(path)
os.rename('a.txt', 'b.klm')
# moving back to the directory you were in 
os.chdir(saved_cwd)
```

Comment: Be wary of doing it this way.  You cannot always `chdir()` to a directory, e.g. what happens under Windows when it is a UNC?  And doing a `chdir()` has side-effects.  I would rather just specify the necessary paths to `os.rename()` directly, no `chdir()`ing.

Comment: Changing global state (the current working directory) is **not** necessary to rename files.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Pathlib library's [Path.rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) instead of os.rename:

```py
import pathlib

original_path = pathlib.Path('a.txt')
new_path = original_path.rename('b.kml')
```

Comment: Why is this better?

Comment: It’s just easier to use this method if all your paths are already Pathlib objects.

Comment: You can already use `os.rename` with `pathlib` objects.

Comment: You don't need to import os if you stick to pathlib methods.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using `pathlib` only without touching `os` which changes the names of all files in a directory, based on a string `replace` operation without using also string concatenation:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/talend/studio/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.bigdata_7.3.1.20200214_1052\components/tMongoDB44Connection')

for p in path.glob("tMongoDBConnection*"):
    new_name = p.name.replace("tMongoDBConnection", "tMongoDB44Connection")
    new_name = p.parent/new_name
    p.rename(new_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

How to change the first letter of filename in a directory:

```
import os
path = "/"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(path + file, path + file.lower().capitalize())

then = os.listdir(path)
print(then)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
import os

files = os.listdir("./pics/") 

for key in range(0, len(files)):
   print files[key]
   shutil.move("./pics/" + files[key],"./pics/img" + str(key) + ".jpeg")
```

This should do it. python 3+

Comment: ... or use enumerate for a slightly more readable version :
for key, fname in enumerate(files): …

Comment: How can you write `print files[key]` and "python 3+" in the same answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you are Using **Windows** and you want to rename your 1000s of files in a folder then:
You can use the below code. (Python3)

```
import os

path = os.chdir(input("Enter the path of the Your Image Folder :  ")) #Here put the path of your folder where your images are stored

image_name = input("Enter your Image name : ") #Here, enter the name you want your images to have

i = 0

for file in os.listdir(path):

    new_file_name = image_name+"_" + str(i) + ".jpg" #here you can change the extention of your renmamed file.
    os.rename(file,new_file_name)

    i = i + 1

input("Renamed all Images!!")
```

Answer (score -2):

os.chdir(r"D:\Folder1\Folder2")
os.rename(src,dst) 
#src and dst should be inside Folder2

Answer (score -4):

```
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path

for f in os.listdir(training_data_dir2):
  for file in os.listdir( training_data_dir2 + '/' + f):
    oldfile= Path(training_data_dir2 + '/' + f + '/' + file)
    newfile = Path(training_data_dir2 + '/' + f + '/' + file[49:])
    p=oldfile
    p.rename(newfile)
```

Comment: Hard-coding forward slash as the path separator and mixing old-style `os.path` with modern `pathlib` is quite iffy. Go all the way with `pathlib` instead.

Answer (score -6):

You can use os.system to invoke terminal to accomplish the task:

```
os.system('mv oldfile newfile')
```

Comment: yes, this will work only on a unix-based machine as `mv` is a unix builtin commandline program to move/rename a file.

Comment: Why would you invoke a terminal and define a UNIX only command when you can do it from python in a multi-platform way?