# Rename multiple files in a directory in Python

Tags: python, file-io, file-rename

I'm trying to rename some files in a directory using Python.

Say I have a file called `CHEESE_CHEESE_TYPE.***` and want to remove `CHEESE_` so my resulting filename would be `CHEESE_TYPE`

I'm trying to use the `os.path.split` but it's not working properly. I have also considered using string manipulations, but have not been successful with that either.

Comment: Your needle is not in the haystack, your haystack has a wildcard, and even ignoring case your result cannot come from that haystack. Care to clean up the question a bit?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to clear it up as best I can.  
I have a folder of files that all are named something like cheese_cheese_type.prj (all have the same first 15 chars, but different trailing 4 chars & extensions)
Im trying to remove the first 8 charecters from the filename (in the example, 'cheese_' would be removed and the resulting filename would be cheese_type.prj

so what Im trying to do is walk the directory, split the file names, and remove the first 8 characters from the filename.
in would be cheese_cheese_type.prj 
out would be cheese_type.prj

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to, but not the same as [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2491222/7758804)

Answer (score 653, accepted):

Use [`os.rename(src, dst)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) to rename or move a file or a directory.

```
$ ls
cheese_cheese_type.bar  cheese_cheese_type.foo
$ python
>>> import os
>>> for filename in os.listdir("."):
...  if filename.startswith("cheese_"):
...    os.rename(filename, filename[7:])
... 
>>> 
$ ls
cheese_type.bar  cheese_type.foo
```

Comment: Im getting an error from windows saying it cant find the file, and it's not doing anything...any tips?

Comment: @Jeff I found it much easier to save the script and place it in the directory I would be running it in. This way, the os.rename method works correctly. The disadvantage is you might end up renaming the script itself. Instead of using `.` as the dir, you could make a variable called `dir` and use that, then prepend `dir` to the `filename`.

Comment: you got the "can't find file' because filename isn't the absolute path. Explicitly call path and os.path.join(path, filename) prior to calling the rename and it will work.

Comment: its better to have full path with the filename passed to os.rename rather than just a file name only.

Answer (score 39):

Here's a script based on your newest comment.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import rename, listdir

badprefix = "cheese_"
fnames = listdir('.')

for fname in fnames:
    if fname.startswith(badprefix*2):
        rename(fname, fname.replace(badprefix, '', 1))
```

Answer (score 25):

The following code should work. It takes every filename in the current directory, if the filename contains the pattern `CHEESE_CHEESE_` then it is renamed. If not nothing is done to the filename.

```
import os
for fileName in os.listdir("."):
    os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("CHEESE_CHEESE_", "CHEESE_"))
```

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you are already in the directory, and that the "first 8 characters" from your comment hold true always.  (Although "CHEESE_" is 7 characters... ? If so, change the 8 below to 7)

```
from glob import glob
from os import rename
for fname in glob('*.prj'):
    rename(fname, fname[8:])
```

Answer (score 11):

I have the same issue, where I want to replace the white space  in any pdf file to a dash `-`.
But the files were in multiple sub-directories. So, I had to use `os.walk()`.
In your case for multiple sub-directories, it could be something like this:

```
import os
for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk('/path/to/directory'):
    for f in fnames:
        os.chdir(dpath)
        if f.startswith('cheese_'):
            os.rename(f, f.replace('cheese_', ''))
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
import os
import shutil

for file in os.listdir(dirpath):
    newfile = os.path.join(dirpath, file.split("_",1)[1])
    shutil.move(os.path.join(dirpath,file),newfile)
```

I'm assuming you don't want to remove the file extension, but you can just do the same split with periods.

Comment: overriding the builtin 'file' is generally bad practice.

Comment: @bukzor 7 years later, I'll expand on that: "overriding builtins is generally bad practice."

Answer (score 6):

This sort of stuff is perfectly fitted for IPython, which has shell integration.

```
In [1] files = !ls
In [2] for f in files:
           newname = process_filename(f)
           mv $f $newname
```

Note: to store this in a script, use the `.ipy` extension, and prefix all shell commands with `!`.

See also: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/shell.html

Comment: What does each line do?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more general solution:

This code can be used to remove any particular character or set of characters recursively from all filenames within a directory and replace them with any other character, set of characters or no character.

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\FolderName')
        for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    # the '#' in the example below will be replaced by the '-' in the filenames in the directory
    newname = path.replace('#', '-')
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your problem is more in determining the new file name rather than the rename itself (for which you could use the os.rename method).

It is not clear from your question what the pattern is that you want to be renaming. There is nothing wrong with string manipulation. A regular expression may be what you need here.

Answer (score 4):

This command will remove the *initial* "CHEESE_" string from all the files in the current directory, using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer):

```
$ renamer --find "/^CHEESE_/" *
```

Comment: npm (JavaScript) ≠ python. One might as well link to the Perl [rename](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL "rename") command.

Answer (score 4):

import os
import string
def rename_files():

```
#List all files in the directory
file_list = os.listdir("/Users/tedfuller/Desktop/prank/")
print(file_list)

#Change current working directory and print out it's location
working_location = os.chdir("/Users/tedfuller/Desktop/prank/")
working_location = os.getcwd()
print(working_location)

#Rename all the files in that directory
for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(str.maketrans("","",string.digits)))
```

rename_files()

Answer (score 3):

I was originally looking for some GUI which would allow renaming using regular expressions and which had a preview of the result before applying changes.

On Linux I have successfully used [krename](http://www.krename.net/home/), on Windows Total Commander does renaming with regexes, but I found no decent free equivalent for OSX, so I ended up writing a python script which works recursively and by default only prints the new file names without making any changes. Add the '-w' switch to actually modify the file names.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import fnmatch
import sys
import shutil
import re


def usage():
    print """
Usage:
        %s <work_dir> <search_regex> <replace_regex> [-w|--write]

        By default no changes are made, add '-w' or '--write' as last arg to actually rename files
        after you have previewed the result.
        """ % (os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))


def rename_files(directory, search_pattern, replace_pattern, write_changes=False):

    pattern_old = re.compile(search_pattern)

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):

        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, "*.*"):

            if pattern_old.findall(filename):
                new_name = pattern_old.sub(replace_pattern, filename)

                filepath_old = os.path.join(path, filename)
                filepath_new = os.path.join(path, new_name)

                if not filepath_new:
                    print 'Replacement regex {} returns empty value! Skipping'.format(replace_pattern)
                    continue

                print new_name

                if write_changes:
                    shutil.move(filepath_old, filepath_new)
            else:
                print 'Name [{}] does not match search regex [{}]'.format(filename, search_pattern)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 4:
        usage()
        sys.exit(-1)

    work_dir = sys.argv[1]
    search_regex = sys.argv[2]
    replace_regex = sys.argv[3]
    write_changes = (len(sys.argv) > 4) and sys.argv[4].lower() in ['--write', '-w']
    rename_files(work_dir, search_regex, replace_regex, write_changes)
```

#### Example use case

I want to flip parts of a file name in the following manner, i.e. move the bit `m7-08` to the beginning of the file name:

```
# Before:
Summary-building-mobile-apps-ionic-framework-angularjs-m7-08.mp4

# After:
m7-08_Summary-building-mobile-apps-ionic-framework-angularjs.mp4
```

This will perform a dry run, and print the new file names without actually renaming any files:

```
rename_files_regex.py . "([^\.]+?)-(m\\d+-\\d+)" "\\2_\\1"
```

This will do the actual renaming (you can use either `-w` or `--write`):

```
rename_files_regex.py . "([^\.]+?)-(m\\d+-\\d+)" "\\2_\\1" --write
```

Comment: Here's another script, you can write `replacement_functions` for it, and run them, and for each of them it will show you a preview of the changes that will be made, with the differences highlighted with colors, and ask for confirmation https://gist.github.com/aljgom/81e8e4ca9584b481523271b8725448b8

Answer (score 2):

You can use os.system function for simplicity and to invoke bash to accomplish the task:

```
import os
os.system('mv old_filename new_filename')
```

Comment: This only works on posix systems.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
import os
for afile in os.listdir('.'):
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(afile)
    if not file_extension == '.xyz':
        os.rename(afile, filename + '.abc')
```

Answer (score 0):

### What about this :

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'_')
p.split(filename, 1) #where filename is CHEESE_CHEESE_TYPE.***
```

Comment: This does not answer the question!