# How to change last letter of filename to lowercase if it is a letter?

Tags: python

I have been given data which cannot be interpreted by my software unless it has a lowercase letter at the end. The data was delivered with an uppercase letter at the end.

Somehow I need to first recursively loop through all folders and find whether the filename ends with a letter and then change it to lowercase.

I think python could do this, but I don´t know how,. Any help would be great!

yours,
Rob

Comment: I've seen very strange behaving software, but only being able to operate on files with names that end in a lower-case letter definitely might make it into the top ten. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def listFiles(dir):
    rootdir = dir
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            yield os.path.join(root,file)
    return


for f in listFiles(r"Your Path"):
    if f[-1].isalpha():
        os.rename(f,f[:-1]+f[-1].lower())
        print "Renamed " + f + "to" + f[:-1]+f[-1].lower()
```

List the files recursively. If the last character is an alphabet change it to lowercase and rename the file

---

Modifying the program as per the poster's latest requirement

```
for fname in listFiles(r"Your Path"):
        newName=re.match("(^.*?)([A-Za-z\.]*$)",x)
        newName=''.join([newName[0],newName[1].lower()])
        os.rename(fname,newName)
        print "Renamed " + fname + "to" + newName
```

Comment: I guess the file ending can be changed in the same way?.e.g C0000F.JPG into C0000f.jpg

Answer (score 4):

```
import fnmatch
import os

rootPath = '/'
pattern = '*.mp3'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        os.rename(filename, filename[:-1] + filename[-1:].lower())
```

Sources:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Python

[Rename Files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python)

Comment: `filename[-1]` instead of `filename[-1:]`, less confusing ;)

Comment: Maybe using `*.mp3` as example pattern isn't the best choice if the aim is to change the last letter of the filename to lower case -- a lower case `3` will still be a `3`, so the code will do essentially nothing.

Comment: I think that a good addition to this answer would be to add `if filename[-1].isalpha():` then do the conversion.  Just to be sure, that is.  Wishing I could delete this now.  It doesn't matter...