# How to rename last letter but not the file ending in python

Tags: python, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change last letter of filename to lowercase if it is a letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314983/how-to-change-last-letter-of-filename-to-lowercase-if-it-is-a-letter)

This post is a follow-up of my previous post. 
The Answer below was from Abhijit.

It checks the last character of a filename and changes it to lower case if it is a character. I need to adapt it so that it checks the 5th from last character instead. e.g fooB.PNG > foob.PNG

Rob

```
import fnmatch
import os

def listFiles(dir):
    rootdir = dir
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            yield os.path.join(root,file)
    return


for f in listFiles(r"N:\test1"):
    if f[-5].isalpha():
        os.rename(f,f[:-5]+f[-5].lower())
        print "Renamed " + f + "to" + f[:-5]+f[-1].lower()
```

Comment: Please be clear and format the question properly.

Comment: I am really disheartened. You asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314983/how-to-change-last-letter-of-filename-to-lowercase-if-it-is-a-letter/8315221#8315221), copied my answer and posted a new question here. Did not care to either care to select the answer as acceptable nor cared to look back to my response to your comment.

Comment: This was already answered in OP's last question, in the same answer from which he copied this code.

Comment: As others have said: duplicate by same user, no credit to author of previous answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
>>> import os
>>> for root, subFolders, files in os.walk('/tmp'):
...   for f in files:
...     if len(f) < 5: continue
...     newf = f[:-5]+f[-5].lower()+f[-4:]
...     print "changing",f,"to",newf
...
```

but looks like you want character before extension instead of 5 char? in that case why not just split the extension from filename and rejoin it after lowering the last char

Comment: I tried the last examples but didn´t get a positive result. Sorry!

Comment: ok ok!! I have used this forum only a couple of times and have to learn the rules! Please don´t take it personally, I don´t mean to insult anyone

Comment: @RobertBuckley, the rule is universal.  You don't take someone else's code without attributing it to them.  That's for this site and every other site.