# Rename files/remove chars from filename

Tags: python, filenames, renaming

I have a directory full of video files that have been renamed to something like:

```
video.3gp~1209384
```

I need to remove all chars from the filename including the `~`.  Any help would be awesome!

Comment: I assume not **ALL** chars and just the ones after and including the `~`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python

Comment: @user2836448: it would be nice if you accepted at least one answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just use IPython for that; it has integration with bash/shell. Just prefix shell commands with `!` and interpolate Python variables in shell commands using `$`.

```
>>> files = !ls *.3gp~*
>>> for f in files:
        newname = f.split('~')[0]
        mv $f $nename
```

Or, if that's not an option (e.g. you can't install IPython or must use pure Python):

```
import os

files = os.listdir(DIRNAME)
for f in files:
    if '.3gp~' in f:
        newname = f.split('~')[0]
        os.rename(f, newname)
```

Both of these assume your files don't have `~` in the part of the name you'd like to keep; it's very unlikely; but if they do, it'd be a really simple adaption in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):    
    os.rename(filename, filename[:filename.find("~")])
```