# i need to rename a multiple files in a folder with numbers increament in python

Tags: python

i need to rename a multiple files from a folder with numbers increament in python.i.e. First file in a folder gets renamed with 1 and second file get a name with 2.like that..How to solve this

Comment: What have you tries so far? Where is your code?

Comment: any news on this question?

Answer (score 0):

You should first **[iterate through files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)**, and the **[rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python)** the files.

It might look like this:

```
import os

# Let's say you want to rename files in the current directory
index = 1
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    os.rename(filename, '_'.join([str(index),filename]))
    index += 1
```

This can be the approach and then you should adapt it to your needs.