# How to rename a bunch of files using python?

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner in python. I need to rename a bunch of files with dates in the name. The names all look like:

- `front 7.25.16`
- `left 7.25.16`
- `right 7.25.16`

I would like them to start with the date rather then *front*, *left*, or *right*, so that `front 7.25.16` becomes `7.25.16 front`.

I have tried using *regular expressions* and *os.walk* and I have run into troubles with both. Right now I am just trying to print the file names to prove *os.walk* is working. Right now my code looks like this:

```python
import re, shutil, os

K = re.compile(r"(\d+.\d+.\d+)")
RE_Date = K.search("front 7.25.16")

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk("path"):
    for filename in filenames:
        print ("the filename is: " + filename)
    print ("")
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename Files in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python)

Comment: You'll need to expand on "I have run into troubles". What specifically isn't working?

Comment: To begin with `os.walk` returns a triple of `root, dirs, files`...

Answer (score 1):

Check this example to rename file as per your need.

```
import os

filenames = ["front 7.25.16.jpg", "left 7.25.16.jpg", "right 7.25.16.jpg"]

for file_name in filenames:
    x = file_name.split(' ')[0]
    y = file_name.split(' ')[1]
    new_name = '{} {}{}'.format(os.path.splitext(y)[0], x, os.path.splitext(y)[-1])
    print new_name
```

output:

```
7.25.16 front.jpg
7.25.16 left.jpg
7.25.16 right.jpg
```

In your code your can use [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) for rename files

```
import os

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk("path"):
    for file_name in filenames:
        x = file_name.split(' ')[0]
        y = file_name.split(' ')[1]
        new_name = '{} {}{}'.format(os.path.splitext(y)[0], x, os.path.splitext(y)[-1])
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
        new_path = os.path.join(root, new_name)
        os.rename(file_name, new_path)
```

Comment: I am away from my computer right now so I cannot check it, but thank you this looks like it would work. Is there any problem if they are all .jpg?