# Change a filename?

Tags: python

I have some files in a folder named like this `test_1999.0000_seconds.vtk`. What I would like to do is to is to change the name of the file to `test_1999.0000.vtk`.

Comment: What have you tried? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename)

```
os.rename("test_1999.0000_seconds.vtk", "test_1999.0000.vtk")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

currentPath = os.getcwd() # get the current working directory
unWantedString = "_seconds"    

matchingFiles =[]
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(currentPath):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".vtk"): # To group the vtk files
            matchingFiles.append(path+"\\"+ f) # 

print matchingFiles

for mf in matchingFiles:
    if unWantedString in mf:
       oldName = mf
       newName = mf.replace(unWantedString, '')  # remove the substring from the string
       os.rename(oldName, newName) # rename the old files with new name without the string
```