# How to rename a link file on Windows with python?

Tags: python, windows, hyperlink, rename, file-rename

I have some link files on windows, then I put them in a folder,  I want to rename them as 0 1 2 ... , so windows can sort them automatically.

I tried `os.rename('src.txt.link', '0')`, but the result is that the "0" file can not be opened.

Is there an another python api to do this?

Comment: Link files on Windows usually have an extension of `.lnk` and when you rename the file you need to preserve it because it's how the file type is identified. i.e. `'src.txt.lnk'` -> `'0.lnk'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename Files in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python)

Comment: on windows it's not need an extension of .lnk, you can try it

Comment: Of course you need the .lnk extension on the filename. If you think otherwise it's because you have the shell configured to hide extensions.

Comment: Actually the system especially hides the extension for .lnk files because `HKLM\Software\Classes\lnkfile` defines the value `NeverShowExt`. If you rename that registry value and change the association of .lnk files to some other ProgId and then back to the `lnkfile` ProgId, you should see the .lnk extension on the names of shell shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename a file with extension .lnk. Looks like Windows blocks that operation. Instead i suggest you copy the file with new name, in your case 0.lnk, and then remove the original file.