# How to rename list of files to new arbitrary list

Tags: python, bash, rename, file-rename

I have a list of files: Wav16.ogg, Wav17.ogg ... Wav76.ogg
that I want to convert to: a65.ogg, b72.ogg ... b32.ogg

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import numpy as np

OldContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("OTWGYNmp3/Wav#.txt").readlines()]
oldName    = np.asarray(OldContent)

NewContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("OTWGYNmp3/Key#.txt").readlines()]
newName    = np.asarray(NewContent)
```

This is the gist of what I am trying to achieve but not sure how to move forward:

```
for i in len(newName):
    os.rename(oldName[i], newName[i])
```

I've looked around and seen different answers but they all involve changing the names by some factor, not replacing with an arbitrary name: [Rename multiple files in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2759067/6943476)

Comment: Show what you've tried. SO is not a free programming service.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Given the filenames in files named `orig` and `new`:

```
readarray -t orig < orig
readarray -t new < new
for((i=0; i < ${#orig[*]}; i++))
do
  echo mv -- "${orig[i]}" "${new[i]}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if it looks OK.

Given sample inputs of:

### orig

```
file1
file2
file3
```

### new

```
filea
fileb
filec
```

The sample output is:

```
mv file1 filea
mv file2 fileb
mv file3 filec
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, this looks like bash. I am new to this but by orig do you mean Wav*.ogg? and I am not sure what new is. I tried using python to create two arrays of the orig and new .txt files. Is this similar?

Comment: you said "I have made 2 text files containing the old names and the new names"; I called them "orig" and "new", but substitute whatever you called them.

Comment: I am using OS, and readarray is not a bash command. I tried read -t Wav#.txt < Wav#.txt but that give "invalid timeout specification" error

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250828/script-for-renaming-files-using-text-file-containing-alternate-file-names

Sorry, I didn't know that bash would be more effective