# Recursively rename files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I have a folder named '12'  and this folder contains following files:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./12', topdown=True):
    dirs.clear() #with topdown true, this will prevent walk from going into subs
    for file in files:
        print(file)
```

Output:

```
ab  1.jpg
ab 0.jpg
```

Now I want to replace spaces in the above files with an underscore to do this I have done:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./12', topdown=True):
    dirs.clear() #with topdown true, this will prevent walk from going into subs
    for file in files:
        r=file.replace(" ", "_")
        os.rename(r, file)
```

In the above code when I `print(r)` it gives me value of space replaced by underscore i.e

```
ab__1.jpg
ab_0.jpg
```

But the os.rename function does not work and actual file names are not changed inside the folder. I get the following error for os.rename(r, file):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "demo.py", line 7, in
>   
>       os.rename(r, file) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ab__1.jpg' -> 'ab  1.jpg'

How can I resolve this error ?

**Edit**:
My question is not a duplicate of [Rename multiple files in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-multiple-files-in-a-directory-in-python)  because on the mentioned link they are using one for loop to recursively rename all the files in the current working directory. In my question I am using 2 for loops as renaming files is one sub part of my entire process, When I use two for loops I am encountering my error.

Comment: Syntax `os.rename(your_actual_file_name, your_renamed_file_name)`. So you should wrtie `os.rename(file, r)`.

Comment: please check the editted question, this question is not a duplicate

Comment: First, there is no recursion in your code. You are providing the wrong name to `.rename()` method. Change as mentioned in about comment or please check the answers in the provided link.

Comment: Its resolved, Ive posted the answer

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are intending to do `os.rename("./12/" + file, ./12/" + r)`? As you are modifying the files in the directory named `12`, not the directory where the Python script was executed from.

Comment: Does this work? I do not have the same directory structure as yours so I am unable to tell.

Comment: I tried cwd=os.getcwd() \ 
os.rename(os.path.join(cwd,file), os.path.join(cwd,r))  but I get this error:     [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ajinkya/Desktop/123/ab  1.jpg' -> '/home/ajinkya/Desktop/123/ab__1.jpg'    Where as in reality this directory exists

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.rename(file, r)` instead of `os.rename(r, file)`.

Comment: It gives the same error: /home/ajinkya/Desktop/123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.rename(file, r)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ab  1.jpg' -> 'ab__1.jpg'
ajin

Answer (score 0):

My bad I had to provide absolute path to rename these files:

```
import os
cwd=os.getcwd()+'/12'
print(cwd)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./12', topdown=True):
    dirs.clear() #with topdown true, this will prevent walk from going into subs
    for file in files:
        r=file.replace(" ", "_")

        os.rename(os.path.join(cwd,file), os.path.join(cwd,r))
```