# How to rename() without race conditions?

Tags: linux, unix, race-condition

If I want to rename `A` to `B`, but only if `B` doesn't exist, the naive thing would be checking if `B` exists (with `access("B", F_OK)` or something like that), and if it doesn't proceeding with `rename`. Unfortunately this opens a window during which some other process might decide to create `B`, and then it gets overwritten - and even worse there's no indication that something like that ever happened.

Other file system access functions don't suffer from this - `open` has `O_EXCL` (so copying files is safe), and recently Linux got an entire family of `*at` syscalls that protect against most other race conditions - but not this particular one (`renameat` exists, but protects against an entirely different problem).

So does it have a solution?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using an explicit locking mechanism instead of relying on an implicit locking in (a wrapper of) rename function.  If what creates `B` is a program under your control, you could possibly use interprocess synchronization primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Linux kernel 3.15 (released in June 2014), this can be done with syscall(__NR_renameat2, AT_FDCWD, "source-file", AT_FDCWD, "dest-file", RENAME_NOREPLACE) (include `<syscall.h>`, `<fcntl.h>` and `<linux/fs.h>`).

This is better than link(), because there is never a point where both filenames exist simultaneously (in particular, with link(), a precisely-timed power outage could cause both names to remain forever).

glibc 2.28 (released in August 2018) adds a renameat2() wrapper, so you can use that instead of syscall.h and linux/fs.h (though you'll most likely need `<stdio.h>` and `#define __GNU_SOURCE` instead).

For more details, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html (though it does, as of writing, not know that glibc now has a renameat2 wrapper).

Comment: >  with link(), a precisely-timed power outage could cause both names to remain forever

This is true of rename as well; atomic only applies to a normally functioning kernel. The behaviour on power loss depends on the filesystem being used (among other things). Rename is still better than link though, because killing the process can leak both files like in the example

Answer (score 15):

You should be able to [link](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/link/)(2) to the new file name.  If the link fails then you give up because the file already exists.  If the link succeeds, your file now exists under both the old and the new name.  Then you [unlink](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/unlink/)(2) the old name.  No possible race condition.

Comment: @Dummy00001: I see. I missed the brackets in the title. +1 then :-)

Comment: However this just moves the possible race condition to the `unlink()` side.

Comment: Nope, the unlink() only happens if you got the link, and that's guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: If you run several different processes concurrently on the same source on a heavily loaded machine on a slow filesystem like NFS, *this primitive algorithm could do serious harm*, including an `unlink()` of a freshly created new source in following sequence, for example: `a:link`, `b:link`, `a:unlink`, `c:creat`, `c:write` `b:unlink` -> the file re-created by `c` vanishes.

Comment: Not so.  If a:link succeeds, then b:link WILL fail - regardless of the load and multiple processes.  If b:link fails, you never do the b:unlink.

Comment: @rettops: What makes you think that `b` uses the same target as `a`?  If both are workers, they usually want to rename the file into their own working directory.  So `a:link` and `b:link` both succeed, and then you have 3 links to the file.  If you do a `stat` later, you cannot be sure that this comes before the `a:unlink`, too, so link count does not work either.

Comment: @Tino: they think that because that's the premise of the question. OP described two processes both trying to rename a file of their own to a common path.

Answer (score 7):

You could `link()` to the existing file with the new filename you want, then remove the existing filename.

`link()` should succeed in creating a new link only if the new pathname doesn't already exist.

Something like:

```
int result = link( "A", "B");

if (result != 0) {
    // the link wasn't created for some reason (maybe because "B" already existed)
    // handle the failure however appropriate...
    return -1;
}

// at this point there are 2 filenames hardlinked to the contents of "A", 
//   filename "A" and filename "B"

// remove filename "A"
unlink( "A");
```

This technique is discussed in the docs for `link()` (see the discussion about modifying the passwd file):

- http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/link.html

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for adding something to an old thread.  And for doing such a long post.

I only know one single way to do a complete race condition free `rename()` in absence of locking which should virtually work on any filesystem, even on NFS with intermittend server reboots and client time warps in place.

The following recipe is race condition free in the sense that at no circumstance data can get lost.  It also does not need locks and can be performed by clients which do not want to cooperate except that they all use the same algorithm.

It is not race condition free in the sense that, if something seriously breaks, everything is left in a clean an tidy state.  It also has a short period of time, where neither the source nor the destination are present at their location, however the source still is around under another name.  And it is not hardened against cases where an attacker tries to provoke harm (the `rename()` is the culprit, go figure).

S is the Source, D is the destination, P(x) is `dirname(x)`, C(x,y) is `x/y` path concatenation

1. check that the destination does not exist.  Just to make sure we do not do the next steps in vain.
2. create a probably unique name T := C(P(D),random)
3. mkdir(T), if this fails loop to previous step
4. open(C(T,"lock"),O_EXCL), if this fails rmdir(T) ignoring errors and loop to previous step
5. rename(S,C(T,"tmp"))
6. link(C(T,"tmp"),D)
7. unlink(C(T,"tmp"))
8. unlink(C(T,"lock"))
9. rmdir(T)

Algorithm `safe_rename(S,D)` explained:

The problem is that we want to make sure there is no race condition, neither on the source nor on the destination.  It is assumed, that (nearly) anything can happen between each step, but all other processes follow the exact same algorithm when doing race condition free renames.  This includes that the temporary directories T are never touched, except after making sure (this is a manual process) that the process using the directory has died and cannot be resurrected (like continuing a VM hibernate after a restore).

To properly do the `rename()`, we need some place to hide away.  So we construct a directory a way which makes sure that nobody else (who is following the same algorithm) accidentally will use it.

However `mkdir()` is not guaranteed to be atomic on NFS.  Hence we need to make sure that we have some guarantee that we are alone in the directory.  This is `O_EXCL` on the lockfile.  This is - strictly speaking - not locking, it is a semaphore.

Except from such rare cases, `mkdir()` usually is atomic.  Also we can create use some cryptographically secure random name for the directory, add some GUID, hostname and PID to make sure it is very unlikely that somebody else chooses the same name by chance.  However to proof the algorithm is correct we need this file named `lock`.

Now that we have a mostly empty directory, we can safely `rename()` the source there.  This ensures that nobody else alters the source until we will `unlink()` it.  (Well, contents can change, this is not a problem.)

Now the `link()` trick can be applied to make sure we do not overwrite the destination.

Afterwards the `unlink()` can be done race condition free on the remaining source.  The rest is cleanup.

There is only one problem left:

In case the `link()` fails we have moved the source already.  For proper cleanup we need to move it back.  This can be done by calling `safe_rename(C(T,"tmp"),S)`.  If this fails, too, all we can do is to try to cleanup as much as we can (`unlink(C(T,"lock"))`, `rmdir(T)`) and leave the debris behind for manual cleanup by the admin.

Final notes:

To help to clean up in the debris case, you can possibly use some better filename than `tmp`.  Choosing names cleverly can somewhat harden the algorithm against attacks as well.

And if you are moving trainloads of files somewhere you can reuse the directory of course.

However, I agree, that this algorithm is plain overkill and something like `O_EXCL` on `rename()` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

From the rename man page:

> If newpath already exists it will be
>   atomically replaced (subject to a few
>   conditions; see ERRORS below), so that
>   there is no point at which another
>   process attempting to access newpath
>   will find it missing.

So it is not possible to avoid renaming when the `B` file already exists. I think perhaps you simply have no choice but to check for existance (use `stat()` not `access()` for that) before you attempt the rename, if you don't want the rename to occur if the file already exists. Ignoring a race condition.

Otherwise, the solution presented below with link() seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: If the file B does not exist, there is still  a race condition if you test for existence - both processes may detect it is not there, and then both do the rename, with indeterminate results as regards which process renamed last. The only solution is for rename() to be atomic and to fail if the new filename already exists, which is what it does on Windows, and what I thought (incorrectly it seems) the C Standard specified.