# Rename files with Python

Tags: python, file, operating-system, file-rename

I am trying to use python to rename over 1000 files in a windows directory that have this naming convention:

```
The.Woman.In.Black.2012.720p.BluRay.x264
```

**The desired naming convention is:**  `The Woman In Black {2012}`

The only important things I need from the original name are the title and date....

I have tried using different variations of string manipulation and I am not getting anywhere. I need help getting started.

I understand I should use the os module to rename files, but what procedure should I try and use to do this task?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: What is your problem,  you want to know how to rename or you want the way to convert file name to your desired format?

Comment: Do they all end with `YYYY.720p.BluRay.x264`?

Comment: Advice: check your code **before** you rename all your files, a process like this is unlikely to work perfectly automatically in every case (I suspect there will be some corner cases). e.g. check `set(years)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def change_filename(name):
    filename = name.split('.')
    wordlist = filename[:-4]
    extension = '.' + filename[-1]
    wordlist[-1] = '{' + wordlist[-1] + '}'
    os.rename(name, ' '.join(wordlist) + extension)
```

This function should do exactly what you want, you just need to feed it the names.

Note: you probably want to add a file extension on to the filename, otherwise it might go wonky and everything.

If you run this on the same file more than once, you'll get a file overloaded with braces, and you don't want that, so here's a reversal function:

```
def filename_cleanup(name):
    filename = name.replace('{', '').replace('}', '')
    wordlist = filename.split(' ')
    extension = '.' + wordlist.pop()
    wordlist[-1] = '{' + wordlist[-1] + '}'
    os.rename(name, ' '.join(wordlist) + extension)
```

That should give you the proper filename again.

Comment: One more question... If I re-run the script multiple times, it keeps adding a layer of '{}' around the file name. For example... after testing and running the script many times, The files now are like so: {{{{{{{{Vacancy {2007} {mp4}}}}}}}}}. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: If you run it on the same file over and over again, it'll stuff up. For example, if we feed `'The Woman In Black {2012}.mp4'` into the function, we split on every `'.'`, and `filename` becomes `['The Woman In Black {2012}', 'mp4'], then it puts braces around `'mp4'` and gets rid of the file extension. If you run it again there is no `'.'` to split the file into and so the braces will go around the whole file name.

Comment: In this case, I am running it on the entire directory by putting the .py in the same directory and executing it.  I've botched all the names now, how would you recover from here?

Comment: You'll probably have to get rid of all the braces, and then go from there. Do you need the code?

Comment: I hate to admit it but... yea.

Comment: Thanks. I've been breaking down your code and playing with it in shell and have a pretty good idea of how it works now. Thanks for the help on this. I'm learning one step at a time.

Comment: This solution won’t work with [`2012 (2009)`](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1190080/) though.

Comment: @poke sorry for the misunderstanding, but anyway the solution should work now (assuming the filename input has an extension on it)

Comment: If I was going to os.walk the directory and put all the files into a list how would I feed it to this function?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with `os.walk` since I haven't used it, but the docs say that it returns the file names as the last element of a three-tuple. I'm assuming it's gonna be a list of some sort, so all you need to do is extract that list (maybe by `os.walk(directory)[-1]`) and feed every element to the function.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. What I am trying to do is run the script and have it use the functions you supplied on all the files in a directory.

Comment: Do you know what `os.walk` does and what it returns?

Comment: With `for data in os.walk("C:\Users\SyFYChryme\Videos\Movies"):`
         `movies.append(data)` I am able to get all the titles in a list. I just don;t know how to take them, one by one and run them through the function to be renamed.

Comment: oh, ok then, all you need to do is just in the for loop, do `change_filename(data)` and that should work (or of course the other function if you wanted to)

Answer (score 3):

```
filename = 'The.Woman.In.Black.2012.720p.BluRay.x264'

# using regular expressions
import re
title, year = re.match('(.*?)\.(\d{4})\.720p\.BluRay\.x264', filename).groups()

# simpler regular expression, matching any format specifiers
title, year = re.match('(.+)\.(\d{4})\.', filename).groups()

# using simple string manipulation if the suffix is always the same
title, year = filename[:-22], filename[-21:-17]

# normalize title
title = title.replace('.', ' ')

# build new filename
print('%s {%s}' % (title, year)) # The Woman In Black {2012}
```

To rename files, use [`os.rename`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename); to iterate through a directory, use [`glob.glob`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) or [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: The second re -- `'(.+)\.(\d{4})'` --  will fail if the resolution is four or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the general format of your titles is:

```
name.name.name.name.name.date.resolution.format.codec
```

in which case I would do this (not tested):

```
import os

TARGET_DIR = r'/path/to/movies/'

for old_title in os.listdir(TARGET_DIR + '*'):
    words = old_title.split('.')
    date = words[-4]
    name = ' '.join(words[:-4])
    new_title = '%s {%s}' % (name, date)
    old_title = os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, old_title)
    new_title = os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, new_title)
    os.rename(old_title, new_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the original naming convention is consistent, you could [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) the original filename string on the '.' character, and then look for a valid year, add the braces, and [join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) it with all the preceding tokens to form the new name.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python) for how to rename a file using python.