# os.rename:TypeError: Required argument 'dst' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python, typeerror

I was trying to rename a file in python.I went to the directory using `os.rename` then tried to change a song name `os.rename('shokilla.mp3, new_shokilla.mp3')` but this error poped up about I don't have any idea
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
os.rename('shokilla.mp3, new_shokilla.mp3')
TypeError: Required argument 'dst' (pos 2) not found`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

> you need to do like this

```
os.rename("shokilla.mp3","new_shokilla.mp3")
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm