# Python - Swap two file directories with each other

Tags: python, filesystems, file-rename

I have a robot and it is set up in a way to take commands from the front end of the website to then run a command on the robot. For example

```
if command == 'CF':
    os.system('aplay /home/pi/sound/wavycf.wav')
```

I need somthing that will swap two files `/images/hud.png` and `images/special/hud.png` to each others directories....I hope that makes sense

Comment: _I hope that makes sense_ Not really. Try again. Also, show us what you tried so far and post your code. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python); swapping two files is no different than two (or three) rename operations.

Answer (score 0):

Just put one into temporal position, move another and than move first from temp to final place

```
os.system("move /images/hud.png /images/special/hud.png.tmp")
os.system("move /images/special/hud.png /images/hud.png")
os.system("move /images/special/hud.png.tmp /images/special/hud.png")
```

or do it everythin using python:

```
# load file 1 into buffer
data = ""
with open("/images/hud.png", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
# copy file 2 into file 1
with open("/images/special/hud.png", "rb") as f1:
    with open("images/hud.png", "wb") as f2:
        f2.write(f1.read())
# save file 1 from buffer
with open("/images/special/hud.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)
# clear memory
del data
```