# How to rename a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My requirement is to rename file and append with Current date.files will come with any format on runtime
My input is like

```
1334.pdf
3214.xlsx
12_32.doc
```

My expected output

```
1334_2018238.pdf
3224_currentdate.xslx
```

Comment: Sounds great. Please let us know how it goes. If you need help, please show that you have done some research, attempted a solution yourself, and ask a specific question about the issue you are coming across.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Comment: You should not be learning Python 2 in 2018. By the original timeline, it should be dead already (though it's now in terminal care on an extension for about a year and a half still). The recommended and supported version of the language is Python 3.

Comment: That answer not suit my requirement

Comment: @Svickie7 SO is not a 'do my work for me' kind of place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) as long as they are on the same filesystem. Otherwise, use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

To get the date you can use `datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S")` and use the output of that in the new name of your file. (see [how to use strftime here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime))

For example:

```
my_file = 'file_1.pdf'
file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(my_file)
date_str = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S")
os.rename(my_file, file_name + '_' + date_str + file_extension)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import os
import time

current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))

os.rename('3214.xlsx', f'3214_{current_milli_time}.xlsx')
```

Comment: This is for only particular file.my input '*.*' output '*_date.*'