# Python: read a string and use it to rename the file

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

I'm completely new to python and I'm trying to rename a set of files using a string on a specific line within the file and use it to rename the file. Such string is found at the same line in each file.

As an example:

- 10 files in the same path
- the string is found in line number 14 and it starts at character number 40 and it is 50 characters in length
- Then use the extracted string to rename the respective file

I'm trying to use this code, but I fail to figure out how to get it working:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  if filename.startswith("out"):
     with open(filename) as openfile:
        fourteenline = linecache.getline(path, 14)
           os.rename(filename, fourteenline.strip())
```

Comment: in case you need a start: `lines = open('myfile.txt').read().splitlines()` `new_file_name = lines[13][40:40+50]` `import os` `os.rename('myfile.txt', 'new_file_name.txt')`. probably this needs some finetuning and spellchecking ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care providing the full path to the file, in case your not allready working in this folder (use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)). Furthermore, when using linecache, you dont need to `open` the file.

```
import os, linecache

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.startswith("out"): continue # less deep
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename) # folderpath + filename
    fourteenline = linecache.getline(file_path, 14) # maybe 13 for 0-based index?
    new_file_name = fourteenline[40:40+50].rstrip() # staring at 40 with length of 50
    os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(path, new_file_name))
```

---

useful ressources:

- [Reading specific lines only (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081836/4464653)
- [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/4464653)
- [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2491222/4464653)
- [python docs - string.strip()](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: Thank you for the code. I tested the code it went smooth till the last line where the below error came across:
 os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(path, new_file_name))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:/path/to/the/file/out0.dat' -> 'C:/path/to/the/file/new_name\n'

Comment: I think it is related to the path length in windows, but I really don't know how to fix it

Comment: no, it's the `\n` (newline). Adding `.rstrip()` to the new filename should help to remove trailing spaces and newlines. (see edited answer)