# change filenames in user specified directory

Tags: python

I have this little script that changes characters from the beginning of filenames in the directory script is ran in. I would like to let the user input the directory to change files in. Im not sure how to implement that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

place = input("Enter the directory the files are in ")
drop  = input("Enter text to remove from filename ")
add   = input("Enter text to add to filename ")

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.startswith(drop):
        os.rename(filename, add+filename[len(drop):])
```

Comment: Use `os.listdir(place)` — `os.listdir(".")` means the current-working-directory.

Comment: I get errors. I listed on another comment

Comment: `os.listdir(place)` gives you just the filenames. To do anything with one of them you'll need to use something like `filepath = os.path.join(place, filename)`.

Comment: If you instead used `for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(place, '*.*'):`, each `filename` would be a fullpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> os.listdir(path='.') Return a list containing the names of the entries
>   in the directory given by path.

Hence just change `"."` to a string containing the path of the directory.

For example, from command-line, you can do:

```
mypath = input("Type path dir: ")
for filename in os.listdir(mypath):
    ...
```

`mypath` can be both absolute or relative path.

**EDIT**

I forgot to say: as mentioned also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python) `os.rename()` needs the full path of the file if they are in a different directory.

Something like this should work, if `mypath` is the full path:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(mypath, filename), os.path.join(mypath, add, filename[len(drop):]))
```

If not, you should build the full path.

Comment: I tried that and I get this error. Its a subfolder Im trying this on I tried a fill and partial path to no avail.                                                                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./renamer.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.rename(filename, add+filename[len(drop):])
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.bar' -> 'boo.bar'