# Return day from a date on python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a method to get the day from a certain date. I have files named with the pattern "yyyymmdd.mp3" (e.g. 20190301.mp3). In my country, that day would be a Friday.

I would like to obtain the information "Friday" from the string shown above and add it to the name of the file like "friday-20190301.mp3". Is there some way to do this with Python? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

Comment: 1. String to datetime : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime 2. Get the day of the week :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python 3. Rename file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python 3. Use the search bar before post...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the day of week given a date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty similar to @ALFA's answer, but this is a full solution:

```
from datetime import datetime

example_filename = '20190301.mp3'

def convert(filename):
    day_of_week = datetime.strptime(filename, '%Y%m%d.mp3').strftime('%A').lower()
    return '{}_{}'.format(day_of_week, filename)

result = convert(example_filename)
# --> 'friday_20190301.mp3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_obj = datetime.strptime('20190301', '%Y%m%d')
print(datetime_obj.strftime('%A'))
```

Once you obtained the weekday, you can change the filename using the [`replace`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) function.

Comment: You could use [`date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to get the name of the weekday.

Comment: If you must use an integer weekday, definitely use [`isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) which is the international standard. `weekday()` is c legacy.

Comment: Edited using `strftime` to get the name of the weekday. Thanks @Matthias

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import calendar

def new_name(val):
    my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(val.split('.')[0], "%Y%m%d").date()
    day = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()] 
    return ('{}-{}'.format(day,val))


print (new_name('20190301.mp3'))
```

Output:

Friday-20190301.mp3