# Rename zipfile with info contained in archive in python

Tags: python, zip

I have 5000 Zip archives that contains a json file with an information (versionName),

I want to rename those zip files, the best way I found to do that in python is
to read the jsons and get the information I need, then rename each zip like that : "Archive_name.zip => Archive_name_versionName.zip"

Here is my python code :

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('/home/AndroidBags/aasuited.net.word.zip', 'r')
print(archive)
jsonre = archive.read('meta_google_play/apk_aasuited.net.word.json')
print(jsonre)
```

Here the result of that script :

> {"appdata":
>   [{"versionName": "1.24.1", "size": 19480447}]}

How can I acces the versionName value and rename the zip file in python ? Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

```python
import os
import json

version_name = json.loads(jsonre)['appdata'][0]['versionName']
os.rename(
    '/home/AndroidBags/aasuited.net.word.zip',
    './aasuited.net.word.' + version_name + '.zip'
)
```

This also moves the zip file to the current work directory.