# Replace filename prefix in a directory using python

Tags: python-2.7

How to change the file name prefix in a directory. I need to replace the   white space in the file name prefix"Mohammed " to "Mohammed".

Directory:

```
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-1.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-1.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-2.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-2.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-3.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-3.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-4.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-4.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-5.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-5.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-6.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-6.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-7.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-7.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-8.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-8.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-9.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-9.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-10.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad _eng-10.wav
```

I need to change them to

```
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-1.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-1.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-2.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-2.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-3.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-3.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-4.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-4.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-5.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-5.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-6.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-6.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-7.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-7.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-8.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-8.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-9.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-9.wav
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-10.txt
C:\Mohammad_eng\Mohammad_eng-10.wav
```

How to achieve that? 
Note: I am new in python scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the following, tested and verified, this will work.

```
import glob, os


print("File rename Sample- rename()")


def replace(dir, pattern, titlePattern, replaceFromStr, replaceToStr):
    for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, pattern)):
        title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
        os.rename(pathAndFilename,
                  os.path.join(dir, titlePattern % title.replace(replaceFromStr, replaceToStr) + ext))


replace(r'C:\Mohammad_eng', r'*.wav', r'%s', "Mohammad ", "Mohammad")
replace(r'C:\Mohammad_eng', r'*.txt', r'%s', "Mohammad ", "Mohammad")
```

Comment: Checked this solution, it is a great solution with "glob module that finds all the pathnames matching", thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/)

```py
# call this script from the respective folder
import os
import re

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    match = re.match(r'Mohammad (.*)', filename)
    if match:
        new_filename = 'Mohammad' + match.group(1)
        os.rename(filename, new_filename)
```

This goes through all filenames and directory names and checks whether the name matches the specified pattern. If so, it will rename the file dropping the space.

Comment: Where do i specifiy the directory path ("C:\Mohammad_eng")?

Comment: Like the comment says: Call the script from the folder `C:\Mohammad_eng`, i.e. in PowerShell type `cd C:\Mohammad_eng`, store this script as `script.py` in `C:\Mohammad_eng` and then type `python script.py` in PowerShell.