# How to rename multiple files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, rename

Im a beginner to python and I need to make a script that renames file names.

My files are in the format Name Surname but I need them in Surname Name

I have files that are like this:

```
C:/Test/Smith John
C:/Test/Jones Fred
C:/Test/Jack Martin Ben
```

and I need them like this:

```
C:/Test/John Smith 
C:/Test/Fred Jones 
C:/Test/Ben Jack Martin
```

I have tried multiple things with os.rename but I really cant get it to work.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code and the error you are getting.

Comment: I have deleted the code with anger. Could you tell me the steps I should approach so I research my way into it?

Comment: [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Comment: Those look like general renaming guides.

Comment: That is how you rename files. Without any specifics why that does not work for you no one can help you. Try again, edit in your code and the error.

Comment: but the problem is. How do I go on of changing my code to something that would allow me to rename files in that way. I know how to rename from 1 thing to another.

Comment: use the below code in your program with proper file path.

Comment: Take the file name, `.split()` and merge the two parts in different order (`split_name = file_name.split(); new_file_name = split_name[1]+" "+split_name[0]` for two-part names)

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Split filename at the last space using `rsplit` (assuming a last name is a single word)
2. Reverse and rejoin to get `<name> <lastname>`
3. Rebuild a new file name and rename the file.

Also use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) package for file operations.

```py
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    source_dir = Path('C:/Test')
    for file in source_dir.glob('**/*'):
        if file.is_dir():
            continue
        name_parts = file.stem.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
        name_reversed = ' '.join(name_parts[::-1])
        new_path = file.with_name(name_reversed + file.suffix)
        # check the result
        print(file, new_path)
        # rename
        # file.rename(new_path)
```

Comment: I think the OP also wants the parts where you use the os.walk method and rename all the files in the entire directory.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import os
path = "C:/Test/Smith John"
os.rename(re.search('Test\/(.+?)$', path).group(1), v.split(' ')[1]+" "+v.split(' ')[0])
```

Comment: There are 1000 files like this. I need a code that would change all of them. There are lots of Name Surname files which need to be changed to Surname Name.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

# change working directory to the (C:/Test/)
os.chdir(“C:/Test/“)
os.rename(“Smith John”, “John Smith”)
os.rename(“Jones Fred”, “Fred Jones” )
os.rename(“Jack Martin Ben”, “Ben Jack Martin”)
```

Comment: Please add explanation around your code. So that OP and future reader can easily understand your answer.

Comment: You should have read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833498/how-to-rename-multiple-files-in-python#comment100219455_56833498) before posting your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can modify the file name by searching the particular string and reverse the file name.

```
path = "C:/Test/"
entries = os.listdir(path)
   for entry in entries:
       old_filename = re.search('(.+?)$', entry).group(1)
       new_filename = ' '.join(old_str.split()[-1::-1])
       modified_path = path+new_filename
       print(modified_path)
```

O/p:

```
C:/Test/John Smith 
C:/Test/Fred Jones 
C:/Test/Ben Jack Martin
```