# Python - add words to file name

Tags: python, append, addition, filenames

How could I append the file name with other characters, before the extension.

For example, I have

```
f = open ('text.txt', 'r')
```

Desired output: `g = ('text_done.txt')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

you can import os on django in order to manipulate the file name.
something like this

```
import os
os.rename(r'text.txt',r'text_done.txt')
```