# retrieve_pdb_file from Bio.PDB.PDBList creates .ent files, not .pdb

Tags: biopython

I'm using Biopython to load structures into my code. I then change them into poses, via PyRosetta, because I want to align my theo structure to the PDB website structures. This is my code:

```
pdbl = PDBList()
native_pdb = pdbl.retrieve_pdb_file('%s' %protein, pdir='/my/directory/path/test_natives', file_format='pdb')
native_pose = pose_from_pdb(native_pdb)
```

but the `retrieve_pdb_file` creates `.ent` files and not pdb files. how do I fix this?

OR how do I load the known PDB structures in order to align them to theo structures and find the rmsd?

Comment: (What are *poses*, and what/who is *theo*?)(*R*oot *M*ean *S*quare *D*istance?)

Comment: The downloaded structure has the extension `.ent` but it's still in PDB format. You don't have to fix anything, unless PyRosetta gives you errors.

Comment: https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.PDB.PDBList.html is the relevanr documentation states 'The downloaded file will be called pdb1fat.ent and stored in the current working directory. Note that the retrieve_pdb_file method also has an optional argument pdir that specifies a specific directory in which to store the downloaded PDB files; NOTE. The default download format has changed from PDB to PDBx/mmCif.' . Don't know try add file_format="PDB" and see if it changes it. You can also try : download_pdb_files

Comment: @greybeard poses hold info about the protein structures, it's an object in PyRosetta. theo = theoretical, meaning the theoretical structures that are produced by the script. and yes rmsd is the root mean square distance

Comment: @JanWilamowski I know it's in pdb format but since it's not the .pdb extensions I do get errors because the pose_from_pdb() object only accepts files with .pdb extensions. thank you anyway

Comment: @pippo1980 I have file_format='pdb' already and I tried download_pdb_files but it's not as useful and adds more time because the files are downloaded to the local computer. thank you for looking into the documentation though

Comment: Don’t have my Linux/python VM with me and not an pyrosetta expart. But I think you should just rename the downloaded file from ent to pdb with os.rename https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

If PyRosetta only accepts files with the `.pdb` extension, simple renaming should do:

```py
from pathlib import Path

native_pose = Path(native_pose)
native_pose.rename(native_pose.with_suffix('.pdb'))
```

Comment: Hi @JanWilamowski, thank you for helping me! This was successful in renaming the file but for some reason pose_from_pdb() is unable to open the renamed file. I get this error:

RuntimeError: 

File: /Volumes/MacintoshHD3/benchmark/W.fujii.release/rosetta.Fujii.release/_commits_/main/source/src/core/import_pose/import_pose.cc:362
[ ERROR ] UtilityExitException
ERROR: Cannot open file "1IUA.pdb"

It must be a pyrosetta issue because the file is definitely there and named properly. Anyway, I appreciate you taking the time to help out! Thanks again

Comment: Are you sure you're giving it the correct (renamed) filename? it looks like it doesn't have an absolute path but merely the filename