# Rename Dataset Strings, From '001.jpg' to convert it to 'Cam001.jpg'. I have to do this for 1000 images and labeled files

Tags: python, string, dataset, append

I have a Dataset of 1000 images and its respective 1000 labeled files. The 1000 images are in .jpg format and the 1000 label files are in .txt format. I want to change the filename of all the (1000) images and all the (1000) label files as follows:

**Dataset (Currently)**
001.jpg
001.txt
002.jpg
002.txt
...

**Desired Result**
Cam03_001.jpg
Cam03_001.txt
Cam03_002.jpg
Cam03_002.txt
...

And want to do this for all the images (.jpg files) and all the label files (.txt files), I want them to retain all the data and simply edit the filename, by adding "Cam03_" before original name.
I am working on Python hoping for a solution on Python.

Comment: Question misses clarity...Deosn't matter how many times I read I keep getting confused...Pls add how our sample dataset look like with column names as Data Frame & How your desired output should like with more examples...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This answer tells how to rename a file in python https://stackoverflow.com/a/2491232/12902578.