How to rename a file with Python without overwriting an existing file?
I'd like to rename a file using Python on Linux, but only if it won't overwrite an existing file.
I'm looking for the same behaviour as:
$ mv --no-clobber old_filename new_filename

As best as I can tell, I can't get this behaviour from the obvious candidates:

os.rename will silently overwrite a file called new_filename when running on Linux (but not on Windows!).
shutil.move just uses os.rename, so it has the same behaviour.

Also, I need the operation to be atomic to avoid race conditions, so I don't want a two step approach which tests for the existence of new_filename, then does the rename if it isn't found.

If you don't mind the platform-specific feature (of mv) then just run mv as a subprocess

@SIGHUP That's what I'm doing at the moment, but I'm hoping for something more Pythonic :)

If you can't do what you need using features of the standard library then there's nothing non-Pythonic about using a subprocess.

@SIGHUP Agreed. But I'm hoping that there's someone out there who has a way to do this with the standard library which you and I don't know about yet!

Why not to use shutil.move?

By the way, it looks like --no-clobber will be deprecated in favor of --update=none-fail.

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python

@YuriGinsburg Because it can clobber existing files.

@AKX What a shame! --no-clobber is so much more evocative :)

@countermeasure To be clear, I don't think they'll be removing the flag anytime soon, but --update has more modes that may be of more interest :)

By the looks of it (coreutils, apple, uutils, busybox), the no-clobber functionality in mvs is implemented simply by checking whether the target name is a regular file using access or similar, and refusing to call the rename function if it is. (I suppose that means there's a TOCTOU issue chance there if the target file appears between the check and the rename call?)
If you want to avoid shelling out to mv, then I guess
if not os.access(dst, os.F_OK):
    os.rename(src, dst)

should do the trick. (If you expect to work with symlinks, make sure this does what you expect for those too.)
